# execute service command through php and bash

Tags: php, bash, apache, service, centos

I want to start a bash script from a html page.
This script is supposed to modify a file and reload asterisk service.
I'm using PHP to do so.

My php script :

```
<?php
$field1 = $_GET["P1"];
$field2 = $_GET["P2"];
$field3 = $_GET["P3"];
echo "$field1 $field2 $field3 ";
$output = shell_exec("/var/www/html/script.sh $field1 $field2 $field3");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

And my bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash
num1=$1
num2=$2
num3=$3
for i in 1 2 3
do
    temp="num$i"
    if [ -z  ${!temp} ]
    then
        :
    else
        echo "${!temp}" >> /etc/asterisk/file.conf
    fi
done
sudo service asterisk reload
```

I tried adding apache to /etc/sudoers, it doesn't work, not even with the ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL rule.

I'm stuck with this issue and can't get it working properly.
The script by itself is running properly, only the reload part isn't working.

Can someone tell me what to do ?
(I'm running CentOS 6.6 with httpd)

Comment: What exactly is the error message? What happens if you run this script yourself?

Comment: I don't have any error message related to that in any log file, that's the problem

Comment: If you run the script directly the service restarts properly?

Comment: using a fresh account with no special permission, the service restarts properly when running the script directly

Comment: Can this be related to any security profile ? I had problems with SELinux  that was blocking the execution of bash from php. Maybe something like this could be blocking ?

Comment: I suggest to echo `$USER` in that script, and check permissions on that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

require tty was set in sudoers file, avoiding the command to be executed by apache.

Answer (score 0):

in the /etc/sudoers: www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/script.sh

try:

```
exec ("/var/www/html/script.sh" .$field1 . $field2 . $field3, $output );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: www-data doesn't exist, it's apache but it doesn't work